# Convincing CPack to properly install shared read-only data under /usr/share

Tags: cmake, cpack, fhs

I am configuring CMake/CPack to install an application which ships with a few read-only shared data files. My understanding is that according to the [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html), such files should be stored under `/usr/share`, ideally within an application-specific directory (*e.g.* `/usr/share/my_project`) rather than directly under `/usr/share`. I am using `GNUInstallDirs` as an attempt to stay within (my understanding of) the expectations of the FHS using the following:

```
#...

include(GNUInstallDirs)

# BAD: Installs files from ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data
# into /usr/share
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/"
  TYPE DATA
)

# GOOD: Installs files from ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data
# into /usr/share/${PROJECT_NAME}
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/"
  DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
)

#...
```

Everything works as it's documented; my questions are:

1. Am I understanding the FHS correctly that (ideally) I should put my applications' shared read-only data under `/usr/share/my_project`?
2. If that's the case, am I using `TYPE DATA` wrong in `INSTALL(DIRECTORY ...)`? That is, should I copy all my data to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}` then use `INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME} TYPE DATA)`. That seems like a waste.
3. Otherwise, if I'm misunderstanding where this type of data should be installed, where should it go, and is `TYPE DATA` the right way to use `install(DIRECTORY ...)`? Or do I still need to use an explicitly-specified `DESTINATION`?

I guess this is a nice way of asking if `GNUInstallDirs` and `TYPE DATA` are fit-for-purpose and compatible with the FHS or not. My main goal is to have CMake/CPack *Just Put Things Where They Are Supposed To Live* without needing to explicitly specify the proper location for each platform's installer.

Comment: "Am I understanding the FHS correctly that (ideally) I should put my applications' shared read-only data under /usr/share/my_project?" - According to the FHS documentation you refer, FHS *recommends* to use subdirectory under `/usr/share` but does **not require** it to be `my_project`. For use `TYPE DATA` you may either set `CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR` to be subdiretory, or install the directory `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_project` (with last component named correspondingly and **without** terminating `/`).

Comment: Sounds like `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME})` may be the cleanest solution; it hadn't occurred to me to change that. I understand the terminating `/` copies directory contents without copying the base directory; it's similar to `rsync` in that respect.